# Add File Summary tab data in runtime in NTFS in WinXP SP3

Tags: delphi, file, storage, ole, ntfs

I have given up tryng to figure out the reason of this issue, but here is the story and hope you could give a tip...

As I develop unique app ( http://code.google.com/p/sedev ) and therefore I need to polish it.
I have to add File Summary ( very useful info in my opinion ) to any created files by the app, so I decided to go with NTFS compatible structure
**edit**: code snippet in which problem occurs:

```
if (FileExists(BaseLocation + LeftStr(GetSSWData, Length(GetSSWData)
              - 1) + '.vkp') = True) then // add NTFS descriptive information to output file
        try
          SetFileSummaryInfo
            (PWideChar(BaseLocation + LeftStr(GetSSWData, Length
                  (GetSSWData) - 1) + '.vkp')); // in my testcase files full path is: C:\Documents and Settings\Kludge\Desktop\sedevrpg\SEDEV_RPG_O_710.vkp
          ShowMessagePos('Patch Created successfuly!' + #13#13 +
              'Please verify created data to www.se-developers.net.',
            ParamStr2X, ParamStr3Y);
          MessageBeep(0);
        except // exception handler does not even fire on exception ...
          on Exception do
          begin
            if (WarningChBx.Checked = True) then
              ShowMessagePos
                ('Unable to add Description to Output file (' +
                  BaseLocation + LeftStr(GetSSWData, Length(GetSSWData)
                    - 1) + '.vkp )', ParamStr2X, ParamStr3Y);
            MessageBeep(0);
          end;
        end
```

**final edit by author**: Problem was in SetFileSummaryInfo(PWideChar('')) because after PWideChar conversion you got CHARACTER, not Array of Characters ( aka Strings ) therefore it is not valid path anymore!

Here is main tutorial: http://www.delphipages.com/articles/setting_file_summary_information-9228.html
**edit**: a better formatted tutorial is [here](http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/File_Summary.aspx).

BUT, the thing is that I just cannot get that damned FileName param to accept any string ... I have EOleSysError exception: "%1 cannot be found" no matter what.

Faulting operand is:

```
OleCheck(StgOpenStorageEx(PWideChar(FileName),
 STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE or STGM_READWRITE,
 STGFMT_ANY,
 0, nil,  nil, @IID_IPropertySetStorage, stg));
```

What I do not understand is why it actually wants %1 MSDOS file name input.
I am not launching app from CMD therefore I highly doubt it needs additional param for File path ...

I have tried all possible String and PString conversions, also tried various param passing methods ...    It just does not work ...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a small console app combined with a small test file that displays the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of FileName? What does FileExists(FileName) return?

Comment: It looks like I somehow managed to forgot to remove PWideChar conversion ... as it is totally incorrect ...

Besides - this should be placed in wiki as sometimes .. after long hours of work ... PWideChar and PWideStrings starts to look so similar ... besides as Delphi 2010 provides al lot of auto-conversion features, it is easy to forget difference between plain Char and String :D

Comment: I was just looking in to it while you edited your answer. PS: I tested the SetFileSummaryInfo(PWideChar(.....)) and all went well (Delphi 7).

Comment: Really? Thats pretty interesting finding ... should this be considered bug or feature?  :) ... hm, maybe is has something to do with native D2010's UTF support, huh?

Comment: Did you try to put `BaseLocation + LeftStr(GetSSWData, Length                  (GetSSWData) - 1) + '.vkp')` into a local variable before converting it to a PWideChar?

Comment: Well, no, ... but would it change something, excluding that it would be easier for SetFileSummaryInfo() itself manage FileName param by not needing to perform inline conversions? Imho few CPU cycles savor, thats all ( after massive testing and profiling sessions results ) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only reproduce your case by specifying an invalid filename. Make sure that you include the full path in your filename.

Comment: Thanks, The_Fox ! No points for direct answer, but still - you helped a lot!